# How can I generate report from msbuild runner for sonarqube?

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I've SonarQube 5.2 with msbuild runner 1.0.2 running fine and pushing results to server. All fine.

I would like to be able to generate reports of issues either as a result of runner or from SonarQube web. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean? You want a kind of PDF with the list of all issues?

Comment: Yes! With list of issues. I know a commercial plug-in exists for PDF. I'm more interested in HTML report. I see that HTML report can be generated as part of pre-commit analysis. I don't see how to make it work for msbuild runner as there doesn't seem to be any corresponding commandline switches or other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `/d:sonar.analysis.mode=preview /d:sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true` to `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe` while issuing `begin` command

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"codequalitysample" /n:"Code Quality Sample" /v:"1.0" /d:sonar.resharper.cs.reportPath="%CD%\ResharperInspectionResults.xml" /d:sonar.resharper.solutionFile="%CD%\CodeQualitySample.sln" /d:sonar.analysis.mode=preview /d:sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true

msbuild /t:Rebuild "%CD%\CodeQualitySample.sln"

"%rctdir%\inspectcode.exe" /output="%CD%\ResharperInspectionResults.xml" "%CD%\CodeQualitySample.sln"

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```